# How to get one table identity column value and how to use that value in stored procedure

Tags: asp.net

I have two tables `UserInfo` and `UserContact`. I inserted data into the `UserInfo` table successfully with an identity column (`ID`). I am using a stored procedures to insert data into the table.

```
UserInfo (Id, FirstName, LastName, Address)   
Usercontact(Id, UserInfoId, ContactNumber)
```

I want to insert second table.how to get Id from first table and that id how to use in stored procedure of second table.

Comment: Need to know which DBMS (and version) you're using.  SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

**For SQL SERVER:** Use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (Transact-SQL):Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

Eg.:

```
Insert Into UserInfo (FirstName,LastName,Address) 
Values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Address);

Declare @id int
SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

Insert Into Usercontact (Id,UserInfoId,ContactNumber) 
Values (@id,@UserInfoId,@ContactNumber);
```

Comment: thanks for reply KPL. I wrote stroed procedure with two tables insertion.but when i am trying to execute first table it showing error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scope_identity() or IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)

**SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()**
It returns the last IDENTITY value produced on a connection and by a statement in the same scope, regardless of the table that produced the value.
SCOPE_IDENTITY(), like @@IDENTITY, will return the last identity value created in the current session, but it will also limit it to your current scope as well. In other words, it will return the last identity value that you explicitly created, rather than any identity that was created by a trigger or a user defined function.

**SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)**
It returns the last IDENTITY value produced in a table, regardless of the connection that created the value, and regardless of the scope of the statement that produced the value.
IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and session; it is limited to a specified table. IDENT_CURRENT returns the identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

*Note :To avoid the potential problems associated with adding a trigger later on, always use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to return the identity of the recently added row in your T SQL Statement or Stored Procedure.*

For more refere this blog post

> http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/